# CentOS dependency yum

Tags: centos, php, yum, repository, dependencies

Well, this is like hell for me. For the second time. Last time I give up and install apache+php on Windows. Now I decide to ask.

A hour ago I install php54w in CentOS 6.7. To do that I add the following repo:

```
rpm -Uvh http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

But I needed to install mbstring and I get a conflict error. So I uninstall php54w I tried to install php (yum install php, 5.3.3). Again I get conflicts.

Then I remove (at least i think I do that) the repo

```
yum remove webtatic-release
```

Well, now it'll work! Yes? No! =**/**

[dependency error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vejKC.png)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I ran "rpm -qa | grep -i php" to find out what packeges php are installed and after "rpm -e" them!

Answer (score 1):

You got that error because your system still has the package `php54w-common` installed. After you remove this, you can continue.

As for webtatic, I would never recommend that. I always recommend you use the [remi repository](http://rpms.remirepo.net/). He also builds the official Red Hat packages, and provides repos with newer versions of PHP for those who need them.

Answer (score 1):

Please also note that PHP 5.4 have reached its end of life, and even is the package available in "remi" repository include some security backports, I recommend to consider using PHP 5.5 in "remi-php55" of PHP 5.6 in "remi-php56" repository (or, of course, keep using the base packages)

See : http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/10/05/PHP-5.4-is-dead